# Properly slicing a list of lists

Tags: python, slice

I have an input stream as follows:

```
data = [[1,234],[2,432],[3,443]]
```

How can I get the second element of every list? I can get the second value of a single entry by `data[0][1]`, or every list in a range with both elements using `data[0:2]`, but how to get just the second element from every list? Is there a better solution than just looping through the list?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use a list comprehension:

```
[lst[1] for lst in data]
```

Answer (score 1):

or use operator and map:

```
from operator import itemgetter
map(itemgetter(1), data)
```