# Python slicing of list of list

Tags: python, list, slice

Say I have a list of lists

```
    >>> s = [ [1,2], [3,4], [5,6] ]
```

I can access the items of the second list:

```
    >>> s[1][0]
    3
    >>> s[1][1]
    4
```

And the whole second list as:

```
    >>> s[1][:]
    [3, 4]
```

But why does the following give me the second list as well?

```
    >>> s[:][1]
    [3, 4]
```

I thought it would give me the second item from each of the three lists.

One can use list comprehension to achieve this (as in [question 13380993](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13380993/properly-slicing-a-list-of-lists)), but I'm curious how to properly understand `s[:][1]`.

Comment: Use numpy array if you want such behavior, though the syntax is slightly different: `a = np.array(s); print a[:,1]` --> `[2 4 6]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`s[:]` returns a *copy* of a list. The next `[...]` applies to whatever the previous expression returned, and `[1]` is still the second element of that list.

If you wanted to have every second item, use a list comprehension:

```
[n[1] for n in s]
```

Demo:

```
>>> s = [ [1,2], [3,4], [5,6] ]
>>> [n[1] for n in s]
[2, 4, 6]
```

Answer (score 3):

The behavior can be understood easily, if we decompose the command:

```
s[:]
```

will return the entire list:

```
[[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]]
```

selecting *[1]* now gives the second list (python indexing starts at zero).

Answer (score 2):

`s[:][1]` means take a shallow copy of `s` and give me the first element from that... While `s[1][:]` means give me a shallow copy of `s[1]`...

You may be confusing somethings that you've seen that utilise `numpy` which allows extended slicing, eg:

```
>>> a = np.array([ [1,2], [3,4], [5,6] ])
>>> a[:,1]
array([2, 4, 6])
```

Which with normal lists, as you say, can be done with a list-comp:

```
second_elements = [el[1] for el in s]
```

Answer (score 2):

`s[:]` makes a copy of `s`, so the following `[1]` accesses the second element of that copy. Which is the same as `s[1]`.

```
>>> s = [ [1,2], [3,4], [5,6] ]
>>> s[1]
[3, 4]
>>> s[:][1]
[3, 4]
```

Answer (score 2):

`s[1][:]` means a [shallow copy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shallow_copy#Shallow_copy) of the second item in `s`, which is `[3,4]`.

`s[:][1]` means the second item in a shallow copy of `s`, which is also `[3,4]`.

Below is a demonstration:

```
>>> s = [ [1,2], [3,4], [5,6] ]
>>> # Shallow copy of `s`
>>> s[:]
[[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]]
>>> # Second item in that copy
>>> s[:][1]
[3, 4]
>>> # Second item in `s`
>>> s[1]
[3, 4]
>>> # Shallow copy of that item
>>> s[1][:]
[3, 4]
>>>
```

Also, `[1]` returns the *second* item, not the first, because Python indexes start at `0`.