# Indexing a nested list in python

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, multidimensional-array

Given `data` as

```
data = [ [0, 1], [2,3] ]
```

I want to index all first elements in the lists inside the list of lists. i.e. I need to index `0` and `2`.

I have tried

```
print data[:][0]
```

but it output the complete first list .i.e.

```
[0,1]
```

Even

```
print data[0][:]
```

produces the same result.

My question is specifically how to accomplish what I have mentioned. And more generally, how is python handling double/nested lists?

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20306494/python-slicing-of-list-of-list/20306506#20306506

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With this sort of thing, I generally recommend `numpy`:

```
>>> data = np.array([ [0, 1], [2,3] ])
>>> data[:,0]
array([0, 2])
```

As far as how python is handling it in your case:

```
data[:][0]
```

Makes a copy of the entire list and then takes the first element (which is the first sublist).

```
data[0][:]
```

takes the first sublist and then copies it.

Answer (score 6):

Using [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
>>> data = [[0, 1], [2,3]]
>>> [lst[0] for lst in data]
[0, 2]
>>> [first for first, second in data]
[0, 2]
```

Using [`map`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map):

```
>>> map(lambda lst: lst[0], data)
[0, 2]
```

Using [`map`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map) with [`operator.itemgetter`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter):

```
>>> import operator
>>> map(operator.itemgetter(0), data)
[0, 2]
```

Using [`zip`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip):

```
>>> zip(*data)[0]
(0, 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

The `list` indexing or nesting in general (be it `dict`, `list` or any other iterable) works Left to Right. Thus,

```
data[:][0]
```

would work out as

```
(data[:]) [0] == ([[0, 1], [2,3]]) [0]
```

which ultimately gives you

```
[0, 1]
```

As for possible workaronds or proper methods, falsetru & mgilson have done a good job in that regards.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
print [x for x, y in data[:]]
```

Comment: Why the `data[:]`? It could just be `data`. (And, doesn't look like OP needs a new list for manipulation)